# PDF4Eclipse - How to set it as a default viewer

Tags: eclipse

I am using Texlipse to write my dissertation and came across the PDF4Eclipse pdf viewer this morning. I installed it (was easy) but I cannot figure out how to set it as the default pdf viewer. At the moment Preview (Mac os X) is used as the default.

I know that I can change the default viewer by going to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Texlipse -> Viewer settings but at the viewer command it ask to select a path to the viewer. However I cannot find any pdf4eclipse executable file on my system...

I can, however, use right click on a pdf file and open with -> pdf viewer which then uses the PDF4Eclipse and opens it within Eclipse. However, I cannot be bother to go through that procedure to to open my pdfs with the internal PDF4Eclipse viewer.

Any advise is very much appreciated.

Many thanks

josh

Comment: Maybe `Window > Preferences > General > Editor > File Associations` helps to set the standard editor. There you can select the editors that appear in `Open with`. But I don't know if it will work with your specific product.

Comment: @his you should post this as an Answer (instead of a comment) so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default editor for file types in the settings: `Window > Preferences > General > Editor > File Associations`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another PDF viewer plugin for Eclipse at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siEclipse.php